# HttpSession and JBoss. What is the effect of the session timing out?

Tags: java, servlets, httpsession

Some code I have inherited creates a session with this line:

```
HttpSession session = req.getSession(); //req is an instance of HTTPServletRequest
```

In the config for the app the value for session-config is set to 10 (minutes).

After that about the only use of the session is to get the session id:

```
String sid = req.getSession().getId();
```

and to invalidate it:

- req.getSession().invalidate();

The session isn't used for storing user data. That is all done by Perl scripts in a database table just using the sid created by HttpSession as the identifier. (A bit of a monster of an application).

So. My question is given the timeout setting I would expect something to fail. At least the line:

String sid = req.getSession().getId();

would return an empty string after 10 minutes?

However it all seems to continue quite happily despite the timeout setting of 10 minutes. Why is this?

with thanks

--Justin Wyllie

Answer (score 2):

If session has been invalidated  by timeout or code, when you do `request.getSession()`, you're creating a new session. You can check this by comparing the values of both ids.

If you don't want the `getSession()` method to create a new session in case there's no one created, you can pass it a `false` as parameter.

If you want "something to fail", you can try to add a value to the session (using the `setAttribute()` method), and check it it's there after the invalidation.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html

Comment: Despite the session-config setting being set to 10 minutes it is the case that if I call this: sid = req.getSession().getId(); at 0 mins and then at 30 minutes I still get the same sid value. So. The session has not been expired? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
req.getSession()
```

Returns the current HttpSession associated with this request or, if there is no current session and create is true, returns a new session.

Looking closely at the first part of the definition, I guess that the session object associated with "this" request object is still not empty. And even if it is it will return a new "object" which of-course is "NOT-NULL".

Answer (score 0):

@Justin Wyllie : try with  `HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);`